# Scheduling w. CP-SAT solver is very slow

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

When I run [this](https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling#program) code from the official documentation with the standard parameters of `num_nurses = 4, num_shifts = 3, num_days = 3` I find a solution in less than 1 second wall time.

When I increase the parameter values to `num_nurses = 40, num_shifts = 30, num_days = 30` I end up aborting the script after 2 hours since no solutions have been found.

I appreciate that with the higher parameters there is a combinatorial explosion but scheduling 40 nurses across 30 shifts for a month is a realistic problem.

What can be done to solve this problem faster for larger parameters? Is it [solution hinting](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/model.md#solution-hinting) or increasing/decreasing the number of constraints?

Comment: hmm, try setting `solver.parameters.num_search_workers = 6`, this will also force you to use `solver.Solve(model)` instead of `SearchForAllSolutions`

Answer (score 0):

This example is actually not very interesting. The biggest problem is that num_nurses != num_shifts, there are no solutions. And this is hard to prove.

Please have a look at this [example](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py).